# Should AngularJS $scope only be used for variables that views need access to?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Or asked differently, is it bad practice to store all variables that are needed in a controller in $scope?

Comment: use $rootScope as best practices, it is useful to define functions in $rootscope because $rootScope is a global, which means that anything you add here, automatically becomes available in $scope in all controllers :)

Comment: No, I'm referring to functions/vars that should only be visible within a given controller. Is it appropriate *then* to use $scope? I would think so because if not it may not be visible during invocation by the view?

Comment: Unless the data needs to be exposed (e.g. accessed from the view) there's no reason to set it on `$scope`--just add it as a private variable in your controller function.

Comment: Can you give an example of what other variables a controller might need?  (Maybe those variables belong in a service.)

Comment: Mark a controller can keep state, but that state may not be of interest to the view. That state most definitely doesn't belong in a service.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following rules of thumb in most situations when dealing with controller data:

- Use $scope variables for data that needs to be exposed to the view layer.
- Use services to share data between controllers.
- Use private controller variables for everything else.